# Need to Cover UnsupportedEncodingException for URLEncoder.encode

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I need to cover the `UnsupportedEncodingException` for `URLEncoder.encode` but didn't get an exception.
My code is;

```java
try {
    return URLEncoder.encode("!@#", "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    System.out.println("exeption:"+e.toString());
}
```

Above code i tried with all kind of inputs but didn't get the `UnsupportedEncodingException`.

Comment: If you want to stub a static method in a non-Groovy class, you need additional tools. With Spock's on-board means you cannot do it. You need Sarek, Mockito (inline mock maker), PowerMock or some other tool with similar capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The potential "Unsupported Encoding" refers to the second parameter in the function. "UTF-8" is a valid encoding so your code will not throw an error.
If you want to throw the exception you can change it to `URLEncoder.encode("!@#", "UTF-9");` since `UTF-9` is not a real encoding.

If you want to know what to do with the exception object [you can learn more here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

Comment: That does not solve the OP's problem. He wants to cover this section in his code with a unit test. Changing production code in order to provoke an exception the code is meant to avoid does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

As others said already, URLEncoder.encode only throws an error if the second parameter is invalid.

If you use the Charset java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8 instead of the string "UTF-8", URLEncoder.encode can't throw an UnsupportedEncodingException, thus removing the need for the try-catch block.

Without the try-catch block there's also no need to test it for coverage